# Wagtail: Is there a way to get all pages a snippet is used on?

Tags: django, wagtail

I am using Wagtail 1.7 and need to retrieve a list of all the pages a snippet is used on. I looked at get_usage, get_usage_url but that didn't seem to be quite what I needed. I am using the sites framework with wagtail and need show different search results based on which site you are on (using elasticsearch). The snippets are the only thing fouling that up at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

`get_usage` uses a generic utils function called `get_object_usage`
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/utils.py#L55

This function

> "Returns a queryset of pages that link to a particular object"

As this is just a queryset, you could then append a filter using the `in_site` filter as per [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.wagtailcore.query.PageQuerySet.in_site).

**Example of using this in your serve method**

```
my_model_instance = my_snippets.objects.all().first() # depends on how you want to get your snippet
query = 'foo'
current_site = request.site # or get this inside your search function
usage_pages = my_model_instance.get_usage() # this is a queryset
usage_pages_for_site = usage_pages.in_site(current_site)
usage_pages_for_site.search(query) # remember search must be done last on a queryset because it does not return another queryset. This searches the pages, not the snippets.
```

**Example of using this inside a template tag**

Create a new assignment tag for use inside your templates. eg. /myapp/templatetags/snippet_tags.py

This [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) is provided a snippet and because `takes_context` is set to true on the `register.assignment_tag` decorator we also get the current context from wherever this tag is used. We can then get the current site from the context and pass that into our queryset that is returned from `get_usage`.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def snippet_usage_in_current_site(context, snippet):
    """Return queryset of pages in current site that use the provided snippet."""
    current_site = context['request'].site
    pages_in_current_site = snippet.get_usage().in_site(current_site)
    return pages_in_current_site
```

Load the templatetags file and use in your template eg. myapp/templates/search_results.html

```
{% load snippet_tags %}
  <div>
    {% snippet_usage_in_current_site my_snippet as snippet_pages %}
    <ul>
      {% for linked_page in snippet_pages %}
        <li>{{ linked_page }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This will generate a list of pages used by `my_snippet` on the current site only. Where `my_snippet` is whatever snippet you want to show the relevant results for.

Comment: Maybe this is a fluke of the site I am working on but all snippets return an empty array for this get_usage().

Comment: To clarify you are suggesting to call this on the snippet model, right?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a bit more clarity and a better example for how to use this inside a template tag. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for all this and I hope it helps people with similar questions in the future. I think something else is going on since I can't get anything but an empty array from get usage.

Comment: Are you linking your snippets with Streamfields or via Snipper Chooser Panels? Snippets used in Streamfields will not show up using get_usage, but there is a WIP Pull Request that will likely solve that in a future version: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3954